# What is the reason of this error "TypeError: Network Request failed" in react native project using Expo

Tags: android, react-native, codeigniter, expo, fetch

I am developing a react native project using expo.
In App, there are several http request.
Now when i input console command "expo start", project is working well(It gets data from backend).
But after i built the project into APK, one error is appeared "TypeError: Network Request failed".
What is the reason?

Otherwise, i check url with postman and browser.

Code is following as:

```
const baseUrl = 'http://example.com/admin/';
const postData = async(url, data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return fetch(`${baseUrl}${url}`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}
```

```
postData('api/login', { ...userInfo })
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  let data = result;
  if(data.state == 200){
    setUserInfo({ email: '', password: '' });
    setProfile(result);
  }else {
     updateError(data.msg, setError);
  }
})
.catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
   alert(error)
});
```

Url is working well.
Backend is codeigniter and deployed.
So, i checked internet permission of androidmanifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Please change http to https

```
const baseUrl = 'https://example.com/admin/';
```